# Field inside a conductor.

Tags: electrostatics

I studied the fact that electric field inside a conductor is zero.  So,  when we are talking about the solid sphere and say that there exists an electric field inside it,  are we assuming that the sphere is not a conductor?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide a reference (or further details) for your claim that the electric field inside the solid sphere. Is this sphere described as metallic or conducting? Or is it described as dielectric or insulating? Or are you asking about a situation in which charges are moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is $0$ if the charges are stationary. Charges in a conductor are free to move. If they stay stationary, it is because the total force on them is $0$. If there was an electric field, there would be a force.

In a non-conductor, atoms hold charges stationary. There can be an electric field, but the charges will still not move.

A third case is a conductor where charges are moving. For example, there is an electric field pushing electrons in a wire. Most materials are not perfect conductors. Electrons bump into atoms quite a bit, and follow a very jiggly path that carries them slowly along the wire. The field accelerates them. The material holds them back. On average, they travel at a constant speed.